# how to get the address of video from android gallery

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, video, gallery

How can i get the address of video from gallery.
for example:
open gallery and pick video
then get the video address : /sdcard/myvideo.mp4

Answer (score 1):

Goto: Android gallery > Mark/ check the video you want to get the Address > Options > details.

Now look at the bottom.